# Hosting my website (IIS) 2 routers & a VMware VM involved - how to setup?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, hosting, dmz

I have a modem-router from my ISP (in UK) this is a **Technicolor TG582n**, and a **D-Link DIR-615** router. These are connected via cable, cable ends in the 'Internet' port of D-Link.

I connect via Wi-Fi to the D-Link, which is needed because of wireless connecting and reliability and internet sharing issues using only the Technicolor garbage.

I would like to host a website and SQL Server at home for experiencing. My OS is Win7, but at the end I would like to use a guest VMWare virtual machine as the server.

I got no joy. Routers' firewalls are disabled. I tried many things, port forwardings, DMZ, simplify things.
That's a bad experience: I also tried connecting via cable a PC with Win 7 OS, set up IIS, directly to the Technicolor, and that time I also tried everything I could (port forwarding, DMZ).
I tried to reach by IP, and specific ports, like 8060-8090...
I got a success by www.canyouseeme.org, but that's all...
P.S.: I tried allow the ports on windows firewall, even disable it. With no other (or disabled) firewalls.

I would appreciate any help, especially from someone who has achieved the same. 2 routers seemed to be the difficulty but after I also got no result with the most simple architecture, I'm really sad.

Comment: Although I don't think it's a duplicate, you may find some relevant information here: http://superuser.com/questions/121168/how-can-i-get-my-routers-to-forward-ports-correctly?rq=1

Comment: @George id you yet not get the solution. I too have been going through this and didn't yet get any solution